# Hibernate JPA One To Many Primary key is not cascading as foreign key in another table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name="property")
@NamedQuery(name="Property.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Property p")
public class Property implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "property_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "property_seq", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "s_property")
    @Column(name="property_id", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=10)
    private long propertyId;

    @Column(name="prop_size", nullable=false, precision=10, scale=4)
    private BigDecimal propSize;

    @Column(name="schdule_all_day_flag")
    private Boolean schduleAllDayFlag;

    @Column(name="schdule_prop_end_time", length=25)
    private String schdulePropEndTime;

    @Column(name="schdule_prop_start_time", length=25)
    private String schdulePropStartTime;

    @Column(name="secondary_phone", precision=10)
    private BigDecimal secondaryPhone;

    @Column(length=500)
    private String street;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PropertyAmenity
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="property", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PropertyAmenity> propertyAmenities;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="property_amenities")
@NamedQuery(name="PropertyAmenity.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM PropertyAmenity p")
public class PropertyAmenity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "property_amenity")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "property_amenity", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "s_property_amenities")
    @Column(name="property_amenities_id", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=10)
    private long propertyAmenitiesId;

    @Column(name="avilable_flag", nullable=false)
    private Boolean avilableFlag;

    @Column(name="last_updated_by", length=50)
    private String lastUpdatedBy;

    @Column(name="last_updated_date")
    private Timestamp lastUpdatedDate;

    @Column(name="master_amenity_type", nullable=false, length=10)
    private String masterAmenityType;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Property
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="property_id")
    private Property property;
}
```

In our project need to store Property and Property Amenities Entities into the database. The
realation between tables are property_id act as Primary key in Property and FK in Property Amenities table. When the data is saving using **propertySearchRepository.save(property)**, property_id PK from Property table is not cascading as FK to the Property Amenities table and getting null value.

2021-06-09 00:20:33.347 [http-nio-9000-exec-2] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: **null value in column "property_id" violates not-null constraint**

I am using spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none, we should not use ddl comands in the production. Please advise, how cascade the Primary key to child tables.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I recommend to you is to set a default value for your collections. In your case, you can initialize `propertyAmenities` with an empty `ArrayList`.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="property", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<PropertyAmenity> propertyAmenities = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then before saving the entities, you need to set **both** sides of the relation like this.

```
Property property = new Property();
PropertyAmenity propertyAmenity = new PropertyAmenity();

property.getPropertyAmenities().add(propertyAmenity);
propertyAmenity.setProperty(property);

propertySearchRepository.save(property);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Now i am able to save the data after setting property object under propertyAmenity                                                            
propertyAmenity.setProperty(property);

Comment: You are welcome, consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it was the right solution to your problem.